# dplyr filter by the first column

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

Is it possible to `filter` in `dplyr` by the position of a column?

I know how to do it without `dplyr`

`iris[iris[,1]>6,]`

But how can I do it in dplyr?

Thanks!

Comment: I really don't know if it is a good way, let alone the best way, but `iris %>% filter(select(.,1) > 6)` maybe?

Comment: Or `iris %>% filter(.[[1]] > 6)`

Answer (score 14):

Besides the suggestion by @thelatemail, you can also use `filter_at` and pass the column number to `vars` parameter:

```
iris %>% filter_at(1, all_vars(. > 6))
```

---

```
all(iris %>% filter_at(1, all_vars(. > 6)) == iris[iris[,1] > 6, ])
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 9):

No magic, just use the item column number as per above, rather than the variable (column) name:

```
library("dplyr")

iris %>%
  filter(iris[,1] > 6)
```

Which as @eipi10 commented is better as

```
iris %>%
  filter(.[[1]] > 6)
```

Comment: Probably should be `filter(.[,1] > 6)`. It doesn't matter here, but in general if you've changed the initial data frame with other piped functions before the filter, `filter(iris[,1] > 6)` will reach outside the pipe to the original data frame, rather than use the piped data frame.

Comment: Just as an example where these two are not comparable - `iris %>% mutate(Sepal.Length=0) %>% filter(iris[,1] > 6)` vs `iris %>% mutate(Sepal.Length=0) %>% filter(.[,1] > 6)`

Answer (score 7):

### dply >= 1.0.0

Scoped verbs (`_if`, `_at`, `_all`) and by extension `all_vars()` and `any_vars()` have been superseded by `across()`. In the case of `filter` the functions [`if_any` and `if_all`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/dplyr-1-0-4-if-any/) have been created to combine logic across multiple columns to aid in subsetting (these verbs are available in dplyr >= 1.0.4):

> if_any() and if_all() are used with to apply the same predicate function to a selection of columns and combine the results into a single logical vector.

The first argument to `across`, `if_any`, and `if_any` is still [tidy-select](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) syntax for column selection, which includes selection by column position.

**Single Column**

In your *single* column case you could do any with the same result:

```
iris %>% 
  filter(across(1, ~ . > 6))

iris %>% 
  filter(if_any(1, ~ . > 6))

iris %>% 
  filter(if_all(1, ~ . > 6))
```

**Multiple Columns**

If you're apply a predicate function or formula across multiple columns then `across` might give unexpected results and in this case you should use `if_any` and `if_all`:

```
iris %>% 
  filter(if_all(c(2, 4), ~ . > 2.3)) # by column position

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
1          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica
2          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5 virginica
3          5.8         2.8          5.1         2.4 virginica
4          6.3         3.4          5.6         2.4 virginica
5          6.7         3.1          5.6         2.4 virginica
6          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5 virginica
```

Notice this returns rows where *all* selected columns have a value greater than 2.3, which is a subset of rows where *any* of the selected columns meet the logic:

```
iris %>% 
  filter(if_any(ends_with("Width"), ~ . > 2.3)) # same columns selection as above

Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
6           6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5 virginica
7           6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
8           6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
9           6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
10          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
11          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
```

The output above was shorted to be more compact for this example.